# How do I remove zero with string format?

Tags: wpf, string-formatting

How do I remove zero with string format ? I used this code

```
Binding="{Binding sure, StringFormat={}{0} dk}
```

for remove zero before digit. But when I start the program I still see zero before digit like that

> 0043 dk

. How do I remove zero using string format in wpf form.

Comment: What the type of `sure`? Is it `string` because your `StringFormat` doesn't explain why you have these 0 in the first place?

Comment: I would agree with @dkozl... you can remove your starting zeros by simply using an actual number instead of a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Binding="{Binding sure, StringFormat=#;}
```